# Storing vegetarian sausages

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, vegetables, sausages, vegetarian

I often eat Linda McCartney sausages: [Linda Mccartney 6 Vegetarian Sausages 300G](https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/products/263123095)   ...but, as I don't own a freezer, I have to store them in the fridge.

As the sausages come frozen, I imagine that means I'm supposed to keep them in the freezer. But I often cook them when I buy them, and then eat over the course of about 4 days while keeping them in the fridge.

I currently have an unopened pack in the fridge that has been there for about 4 days... would these be safe to cook and eat? and if so, how long could I actually leave them for (cooked or uncooked) and still be safe?

Comment: You could/should directly ask https://lindamccartneyfoods.co.uk/contact-us/

Comment: @Max I suggest you post that as an answer, because that's really the only answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could/should directly ask the sausage maker, if you do, report back and edit your question (or answer, I'm not certain which is proper).

lindamccartneyfoods.co.uk/contact-us